# ASP.NET Application lifecycle - Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, .net, global-asax, application-start

Having a read of the application lifecycle in IIS 7.0, on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb470252(v=vs.100).aspx) and confused by the following line about halfway down , "The first time that an ASP.NET page or process is requested in an application, a new instance of the HttpApplication class is created. However, to maximize performance, HttpApplication instances might be reused for multiple requests.". That would suggest that discounting performance, the majority of the time a new instance of the HttpApplication class is created per request.

If that is correct, that would mean Application_Start firing on each request. I only ever thought it fired once when the appdomain is started

Comment: What do you mean by _"discounting performance"_?  Your claim _"the majority of the time a new instance of the HttpApplication class is created per request."_ is not correct.

Comment: "HttpApplication instances might be reused" - infers it is not always reused

Comment: Then you should ask the question _"When will an HttpApplication be reused?"_, not make assumptions. :)

Comment: And if it is not always reused what stops if continiously firing the Application_Start event each time a new instance of the HttpApplication class is created

Comment: explained here http://odetocode.com/articles/89.aspx

Comment: What is explained there? Please note the article is 10 years old.